# Why isn't the value from my dropbox being inserted into my database?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a script that I am writing and I have encounted a problem. I can not get the information from a dropbox to submit into a MySQL database.

Everything will show up in the database except for the item from the dropbox.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="work.php" method="post">


<table>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Email" tabindex="1" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Messgae:</td>
<td><textarea name="Message" 
rows = "7"
cols = "35"
tabindex = "2" /></textarea>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<Td>Time</td>

<td>
<select name="hour" tabindex="3">
<option value="1">1AM</option>
<option value="2">2AM</option>
<option value="3">3AM</option> 
<option value="4">4AM</option>
<option value="5">5AM</option>
<option value="6">6AM</option>
<option value="7">7AM</option>
<option value="8">8AM</option>
<option value="9">9AM</option>
<option value="10">10AM</option>
<option value="11">11AM</option>
<option value="12">12PM</option>
<option value="13">1PM</option>
<option value="14">2PM</option>
<option value="15">3PM</option>
<option value="16">4PM</option>
<option value="17">5PM</option>
<option value="18">6PM</option>
<option value="19">7PM</option>
<option value="20">8PM</option>
<option value="21">9PM</option>
<option value="22">10PM</option>
<option value="23">11PM</option>
<option value="24">12AM</option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

And then here is work.php

```
<?php
$time = $_POST['hour'];
$email1 = $_POST['Email'];
$message1 = $_POST['Message'];

mysql_connect ('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypassword') or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("mydatabase");

$query="INSERT INTO Reminder (Email, Message, Time)
VALUES
('$email1','$message1','$time')";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error submitting');

echo "You Chose: " .$time ;

?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Change `'Error submitting'` to `mysql_error()` for details. Also, [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Oh man... second the Bobby Tables comment. I'm pretty sure that should be two word response to any post that is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @james - What is the content of the `$_POST['Message']` that you're testing with? Given that you don't escape your inputs, you might accidentally be injecting SQL in the message.

Comment: What data type is the Time field?

Comment: @stevether No it is not returning any errors.

Comment: The $_post[message] can be whatever the user decides to type. However that informtion shows up just fine I just cn not get it to pull and thing from the dropdown and place it into mysql table database